# How can I disable my ability to type the `git commit` command in a bash shell?

Tags: bash, git

tl;dr: Is there a way to get my shell to reject anything I type that begins with `git commit`? It would allow me to run scripts with `git commit` in them, but not allow any command I type to begin with that prefix.

More info: My team uses `git` for source control, as well as this package called [Commitizen](https://github.com/commitizen/cz-cli) that gives a fancy changelog/autoversioning in the commit history when using the `git cz` command. However, `git commit` still works. This is a problem for me, because I have a habit of using the regular old `git commit` still.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to create a function:

```
git() { if [[ "$1" != "commit" ]]; then command git "${@}"; fi; }
```

or shorter:

```
git() { [[ "$1" != "commit" ]] && command git "${@}"; }
```

---

See: `help command`